# "MySQL syntax error" while creating a function

Tags: mysql, function, syntax

"#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE FUNCTION TavoliLiberi (dataora DATETIME) RETURN BOOL BEGIN DECLARE prese' at line 3" in this function:

```
DELIMITER $

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS TavoliLiberi;

CREATE FUNCTION TavoliLiberi (dataora DATETIME) RETURN BOOL
BEGIN
DECLARE presenti BOOL;
DECLARE numPrenotazioni INT;
DECLARE numTavoli INT;

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO numPrenotazioni
FROM Prenotazioni
WHERE DataOra = dataora;

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO numTavoli
FROM Tavoli;

IF (numPrenotazioni < numTavoli) THEN
    SET presenti = TRUE;
ELSE
    SET presenti = FALSE;
END IF;

RETURN presenti;
END $

DELIMITER ;
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your delimiter preference is set in the wrong place. Try the following:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS TavoliLiberi;

DELIMITER $

CREATE FUNCTION TavoliLiberi (dataora DATETIME) RETURN BOOL
....
....
```

Comment: In the function declaration is RETURNS not RETURN "CREATE FUNCTION TavoliLiberi (dataora DATETIME) RETURNS BOOL".

Comment: [SOLVED] The problem was the "RETURN" instead of "RETURNS" like  Luis G. Costantini R. suggest me, but only uploading it from terminal and not importing it with phpMyAdmin, it was processed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your delimiter changes  try this instead

```
DELIMITER $

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS TavoliLiberi$
```

keep the rest the same