# Repeated syntax errors while attempting to create a lookup function that finds players by ID

Tags: mysql

While I'm attempting to make a mySQL function to find a player by their ID, I'm getting repeated syntax errors no matter what I fix, and I'm unclear as to what I'm doing wrong. I've tried reading through other source materials on here to help, but anything I've tried hasn't been successful.

I've tried reading through [Error while using lookup function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45209903/error-while-using-lookup-function) and ["MySQL syntax error" while creating a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16924379/mysql-syntax-error-while-creating-a-function) which I don't think really pertain to my syntax errors, though I'm really new to coding functions in mysql, so I'm unsure what my problems even are.

```
delimiter //
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS findRaider//
CREATE FUNCTION findRaider(ID INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
BEGIN
DECLARE NAME_FOUND VARCHAR DEFAULT " ";
SELECT name INTO NAME_FOUND FROM players WHERE player_id=ID;
RETURN NAME_FOUND;
END;//
delimiter ;
```

Expected: SELECT findRaider(1); RETURNS "Seranul"

Actual:

ERROR 1327(42000) Undeclared variable: NAME_FOUND

ERROR 1064(42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'RETURN NAME_FOUND' at line 1

ERROR 1064(42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 1

Comment: Hi, asking about a final project where making a function is a requirement for the final project. Please refrain from commenting on things that don't actually help anyone at all.

Comment: `varchar` (in your declaration) needs to specify a length (e.g. `DECLARE NAME_FOUND VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT " ";`. Not sure why your errors do not tell you about that, so it might be something different (but the rest looks fine.) Do you get the errors when specifying the function or when executing it? Because the errors look a bit as if your delimiter didn't work (and they should appear when you try to specify the function). You may need to clarify how you execute that code, the delimiter might not work there (it is a client specific thing, so using it doesn't make sense in every context).